# How to prevent a malicious function from accessing the heap memory that it is not expected to access?

Tags: c

For a given process, the heap space is shared among all the functions, which can result in some security concerns. In the following code, for example, the function *main()* is expecting the function *foo()* to only access the 1024 bytes allocated to *p*. But the function *foo()*, if it is malicious, can access the memory out of that range.

One of the approaches to prevent this from happening is to restrict *foo()* to only access the 1024 bytes allocated to *p*. Is it necessary to do this? If yes, how can we implement this capability, or is there any other approach to achieve this goal?

```
void foo(char *p){
     printf("value of (p + 2048) is %x\n", *(p + 2048));
}

void main(void){
     size_t size = 1024;
     char *p = malloc(size);

     foo(p);
}
```

Comment: If you're anticipating being linked to malicious code, then you've already lost. Avoiding mistakes is one thing, but malicious code that you hand execution to already has what it needs; if you do weird stuff to deny it access to specific data in memory, it can just undo that. The solution is: Don't link to untrusted code.

Comment: There's no way to restrict `foo`. You can tell `foo` what the valid area is, but that's all.

Comment: You might want to learn about the differences between _processes_ and _threads_ and why these two still exist in parallel.

Comment: @QiZhang Which platform your are working on?

Comment: @MNS I am working on Linux.

Comment: @QiZhang Consider using `mprotect` as explained [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to restrict `foo()` to accessing only the 1024 bytes allocated for it. A malicious function can always *attempt* to access past the buffer allocated for it. Some damage it may cause (such as denial-of-service attack by crashing the main service) can be limited by ensuring that `foo()` is called in a separate process as a user with limited privilege (see [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)).

However, the restriction to access only a limited amount of buffer is usually implemented with the following measures where we assume that `foo()` is ready to cooperate with its caller. These measures are pointless if `foo()` is intentionally trying to do harm.

1. Pass the size around: Pass the size of the allocated buffer to the function `foo()`.
2. Code carefully: Write the function `foo()` carefully such that it respects the size of the allocated buffer passed to it and never accesses memory beyond this allocated buffer.
3. Link to trusted code only: If `foo()` belongs to a third-party code, ensure that the third-party code can be trusted.

For example,

```
void foo(char *p, size_t size){
    /* printf("value of (p + 2048) is %x\n", *(p + 2048)); */
    /* Ensure that this function does not access memory only between
       p[0] and p[size - 1], inclusive. */ 
}

void main(void){
     size_t size = 1024;
     char *p = malloc(size);

     foo(p, size);
}
```

There are only two situations when the function `foo()` may act maliciously.

1. Function `foo()` relies on external input to decide the memory location to be accessed and that external input can somehow cause `foo()` to access memory beyond `p[size - 1]`. This is [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and needs to be avoided by input validation (code carefully; see point 2 above).
2. The function `foo()` comes from another library that you do not trust. Using a library that you do not trust is a bad idea anyway. That library could do things far more worse than buffer overflow. So one has to ensure that the library is good and behaves well before using it. One must never link to an untrusted library (link to trusted code only; see point 3 above).

Comment: That is not exactly what OP asks for and does not answer the question. Maybe that is some plug-in.

Comment: @Olaf what does OP mean, btw?

Comment: @Olaf The OP wants to know how to restrict `foo()` to accessing only the 1024 bytes allocated for it. My answer answers that this cannot be done in the strictest sense and adds some commentary about how this is usually done with careful coding and using only trusted third-party code. I see no mention of plug-ins in the question, although I tried to address the possibility of `foo()` coming from third-party code. What do you think the OP is asking? Why don't you add your own answer that you believe answers what the OP is asking?

Comment: @QiZhang - OP is short for Original Poster (the person that originally posted the question)

Comment: @SusamPal: OP apparently asks about protection against malicious code, i.e. code that intentionally does harm, not friendly code. Your answer is pointless, as it just states common programming practice.